# How to get search results that contain given subword with NEST?

Tags: c#, asp.net, elasticsearch, nest

We are using NEST in c# .NET project to get search results from Elasticsearch with this query:

```cs
var response = await client.SearchAsync<Document>(
        s => s.Query(q => q.Match(m => m
                               .Field(f => f.displayName)
                               .Query(s))));
```

Problem is it returns all results that contain separate word s in displayName. We would like to get all results where displayName contains subword s. For example if s="ca" we would like to get document with displayName="my cat". How can I do it in NEST or Sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with this query:

```cs
// Make transformation "my cat" => "*my* *cat*"
var splited = searchTerms.Split(new char[] { ' ' });
var transformedSearchTerms = splited.Aggregate("", (w1, w2) => w1 + (w1 == "" ? "" : " ") + "*" + w2 + "*");

// Search for documents that contain all given subwords
var response = await client.SearchAsync<Document>(
                s => s.Query(q =>
                        q.QueryString(qs => qs
                            .DefaultField(f => f.displayName)
                            .Query(transformedSearchTerms)
                            .DefaultOperator(Operator.And)
                        )));
```

Comment: Bear in mind that the search performance of such a query with be relatively slower with this approach compared to generating ngram tokens at index time.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at indexing the `displayName` field with a [custom analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/writing-analyzers.html) that includes [edgengram token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenfilter.html).

With such a token filter, it'll generate ngrams from the start of each token generated by the tokenizer.